# Loading a class from command line argument

Tags: class, scala

Having a class name passed as a command line argument.

```
$program-name class-name
```

How can I instantiate an object from this class in Scala? In other words, is it possible to get an object from the class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example:

```
Class.forName("java.lang.String").newInstance
```

Comment: And how to do the opposite? If I have an object, how to get the class name?

Comment: @Nabegh - object.getClass.getName

Comment: `val t = Class.forName("ClassName").newInstance`
`t.print()`

This is failing to compile. Class "ClassName" does have a method print()

Comment: @Nabegh - that's strange. But does that "ClassName" have "print" method?

Comment: @Nabegh `val t = Class.forName("ClassName").newInstance.asInstanceOf[ClassName]`. The problem is that java reflection will return `Object` in a lot of places.

Answer (score 2):

As you can call all java methods in scala, you can call `Class.forName(classname)`.